# Find CDF of ${X_N}$ where $N=min\{n≥1:Xn>X_0\} $

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let ${Xr:r≥0}$
be independent and identically distributed random variables with density function $f$
and distribution function $F$.

Let
$ N=min\{n≥1:Xn>X_0\} $
Given that for some $x∈R,F(x)=a$ the value of $F_{X_N}(x)$
is ....

Since the probability that a sample from a random variable is larger than another sample from same random variable is $.5$ given independence, thus $P(N=n) = 2^{-n} $. (As $n-1$ samples need to be smaller $(2^{-(n-1)})$ and the last sample need to be greater $(2^{-1}) $ ).  CDF of this would be summation of $2^{-x} $ from $1$ to $x$ which is $1-2^{-x} $.

However, what I don't understand is what the question is trying to ask.  Since it is mentioned in the question that all $X_N$ are form the same distribution. $F_{X_N} $ should also be $a$. But I don't think that is what is being asked here.

Comment: You need to fix $N$. Start from $P(X_N\le x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n \le x, N=n)$

Comment: What is the value of $X_0$? Clearly this affects the distribution of $X_N$...